# How to output a number in nasm binary format?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

Hello there is a code on nasm that outputs the processor signature as a decimal number through the call printf %u function how do I output in binary (1010000011011100011)?
x86 asm windows console.

```
global main

extern printf
;extern memset
extern ExitProcess@4

segment .data
    ModelStr    db  'Signature: %i', 10, 0


segment .code
main:
    pushfd
    pop eax
    mov ebx, eax
    xor eax, 200000h
    push eax
    popfd
    pushfd
    pop eax
    cmp eax, ebx
    jne CPUIDSupp
    jmp @exit
CPUIDSupp:
    mov eax, 1
    cpuid
    push  eax
    push  eax
    push ModelStr
    call printf    
    ;push 32
    ;push dword 0
    ;push Buf
    ;call memset

;1010000011011100011 bin
;329443 dec
;506E3h hex


@exit:
    push dword 0
    call ExitProcess@4
```

Comment: You have to write a function which generates the appropriate string. `printf` doesn't support binary number output.

Comment: Please help me wplease help me write this functionrite this function.